# Pivoting data with varying width from wide to long with flexible call (to be used in loop)

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, tidyr

I need to pivot some wide time-series data, that is varying width regard to width using Tidyr's `pivot_longer()`.

The data is quarterly, but I receive the data in both years-blocks (with with four quarters) and in six months blocks (with only two quarters), i.e. the data is *varying with regard to width*.

I would like to find a **simple** and **flexible** solution that can be used in a loop, as I need to import many years and six months blocks (and, as I need to convince my research group to use R, I am asking here for a *simple*, *smart*, and *clean* solution using (preferably) Tidyverse).

The data looks kind of like this in the years-blocks:

```
dta_wide1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "peach", "dragonfruit", "honeydew", "huckleberry", "", ""), V2 = c("ABC", "some info", "Store A", "", "As of 31/03/2019", "label1", "", "7", "5", "6", "1", "(a) some useless clutter", "(b) more not relevent information"), V3 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.5", "0.4", "0.8", "0.3", "", ""), V4 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "21", "21", "87", "21", "", ""), V5 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.3", "0.1", "0.4", "0.2", "", ""), V6 = c("", "", "", "", "As of 30/06/2019", "label1", "", "5", "2", "3", "7", "", ""), V7 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.46", "0.72", "0.7", "0.8", "", ""), V8 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "19", "22", "85", "25", "", ""), V9 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.4", "0.1", "0.3", "0.2", "", ""), V10 = c("", "", "", "", "As of 30/09/2019", "label1", "", "4", "1", "4", "8", "", ""), V11 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.1", "0.3", "0.6", "0.22", "", ""), V12 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "21", "23", "71", "27", "", ""), V13 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.3", "0.1", "0.4", "0.2", "", ""), V14 = c("", "", "", "", "As of 31/12/2019", "label1", "", "8", "6", "9", "9", "", ""), V15 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.7", "0.87", "0.55", "0.33", "", ""), V16 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "24", "25", "99", "35", "", ""), V17 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.3", "0.1", "0.4", "0.2", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

and like this in the six months blocks:

```
dta_wide2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "peach", "dragonfruit", "honeydew", "huckleberry", "", ""), V2 = c("ABC", "some info", "Store A", "", "As of 31/03/2020", "label1", "", "2", "3", "4", "8", "(a) some useless clutter", "(b) more not relevent information"), V3 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.1", "0.2", "0.3", "0.8", "", ""), V4 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "10", "11", "12", "9", "", ""), V5 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.3", "0.1", "0.4", "0.2", "", ""), V6 = c("", "", "", "", "As of 30/06/2020", "label1", "", "4", "6", "8", "16", "", ""), V7 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.22", "0.33", "0.44", "0.55", "", ""), V8 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "11", "12", "13", "10", "", ""), V9 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.4", "0.1", "0.3", "0.2", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

i.e. (for the six months block)

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
dta_wide2 %>% as_tibble
# A tibble: 13 x 9
V1       V2             V3     V4      V5     V6       V7    V8     V9    
<chr>    <chr>          <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
   1 ""       "ABC"          ""     ""      ""     ""       ""    ""     ""    
2 ""       "some info"    ""     ""      ""     ""       ""    ""     ""    
3 ""       "Store A"      ""     ""      ""     ""       ""    ""     ""    
4 ""       ""             ""     ""      ""     ""       ""    ""     ""    
5 ""       "As of 31/03/~ ""     ""      ""     "As of ~ ""    ""     ""    
6 ""       "label1"       ""     "label~ ""     "label1" ""    "labe~ ""    
7 ""       ""             "labe~ "label~ "labe~ ""       "lab~ "labe~ "labe~
8 "peach"  "2"            "0.1"  "10"    "0.3"  "4"      "0.2~ "11"   "0.4" 
9 "dragon~ "3"            "0.2"  "11"    "0.1"  "6"      "0.3~ "12"   "0.1" 
10 "honeyd~ "4"            "0.3"  "12"    "0.4"  "8"      "0.4~ "13"   "0.3" 
11 "huckle~ "8"            "0.8"  "9"     "0.2"  "16"     "0.5~ "10"   "0.2" 
12 ""       "(a) some use~ ""     ""      ""     ""       ""    ""     ""    
13 ""       "(b) more not~ ""     ""      ""     ""       ""    ""     ""
```

in `dta_wide2` the date keys are floting around like this

```
> dta_wide2[5,] %>% str_sub(start= -10) %>% lubridate::dmy()
[1] NA           "2020-03-31" NA           NA           NA          
[6] "2020-06-30" NA           NA           NA
```

so I try to tidy it up like this

```
dta_wide2 %>% 
   add_column(date1 = dta_wide2[5,2] %>% str_sub(start= -10) %>% lubridate::dmy(), .before = 2)  %>% 
   add_column(date2 = dta_wide2[5,6] %>% str_sub(start= -10) %>% lubridate::dmy(), .before = 6) %>% 
   add_column(store = dta_wide2[3,2], .before = 2) %>% as_tibble

# A tibble: 13 x 12
   V1    store date1      V2    V3    V4    date2      V5    V6    V7   
   <chr> <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <date>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 "ABC" ""    ""    2020-06-30 ""    ""    ""   
 2 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 "som~ ""    ""    2020-06-30 ""    ""    ""   
 3 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 "Sto~ ""    ""    2020-06-30 ""    ""    ""   
 4 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 ""    ""    ""    2020-06-30 ""    ""    ""   
 5 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 "As ~ ""    ""    2020-06-30 ""    "As ~ ""   
 6 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 "lab~ ""    "lab~ 2020-06-30 ""    "lab~ ""   
 7 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 ""    "lab~ "lab~ 2020-06-30 "lab~ ""    "lab~
 8 "pea~ Stor~ 2020-03-31 "2"   "0.1" "10"  2020-06-30 "0.3" "4"   "0.2~
 9 "dra~ Stor~ 2020-03-31 "3"   "0.2" "11"  2020-06-30 "0.1" "6"   "0.3~
10 "hon~ Stor~ 2020-03-31 "4"   "0.3" "12"  2020-06-30 "0.4" "8"   "0.4~
11 "huc~ Stor~ 2020-03-31 "8"   "0.8" "9"   2020-06-30 "0.2" "16"  "0.5~
12 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 "(a)~ ""    ""    2020-06-30 ""    ""    ""   
13 ""    Stor~ 2020-03-31 "(b)~ ""    ""    2020-06-30 ""    ""    ""   
# ... with 2 more variables: V8 <chr>, V9 <chr>
```

Now, I need to *pivot it longer* using, if I get it corret, `pivot_longer`, however my challenge is how -- when I also get data that looks like `dta_wide1`, i.e. with four quarters -- do I do it in a flexible way that I can use for both `dta_wide1` and `dta_wide2`.

How can I make this work?

Here's where I'm currently at, but it’s not right, not flexible, and not simply

```
dta_wide2_foo <- dta_wide2
names(dta_wide2_foo) <- c('goods', paste0(dta_wide2[6,2:5], dta_wide2[7,2:5], sep = '_1'), paste0(dta_wide2[6,2:5], dta_wide2[7,2:5], sep = '_2'))
dta_wide2_foo %>% 
   add_column(date1 = dta_wide2[5,2] %>% str_sub(start= -10) %>% lubridate::dmy(), .before = 2)  %>% 
   add_column(date2 = dta_wide2[5,6] %>% str_sub(start= -10) %>% lubridate::dmy(), .before = 6) %>% 
   add_column(store = dta_wide2[3,2], .before = 2) %>% as_tibble %>% .[8:11,]  %>%
   pivot_longer(-c(goods, store, date1, date2), values_to = "Value", names_to = "variable") %>% print(n = 100)
```

Or, some generic snippet, that is not neither simple, smart, or clean, but it could be used to get the positions of the dates in both sample data in a loop:

```
dta <- dta_wide2
dta[5,] %>% str_sub(start= -10) %>% lubridate::dmy() %>% { which(!is.na(.)) }
[1] 2 6
```

Or, cleaner:

```
dta <- dta_wide1
dta[5,] %>% grep("As ",.)
[1]  2  6 10 14
```

#### Update 2020-06-08 07:45:18Z

My goal is to combine the long data sets to able to plot the data, ([Wimpel suggest below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153859/pivoting-data-with-varying-width-from-wide-to-long-with-flexible-call-to-be-use#comment110057843_62198419) that I combine my varying wide data sets, i.e. `dta_wide1`, `dta_wide2`, `...` `dta_widen`, using a lapply() call) I imagine data that looks something like this:

```
> dta_long
# A tibble: 96 x 5
   product label   value date       store  
   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <date>     <chr>  
 1 peach   label1   7    2019-03-31 Store A
 2 peach   label2   0.5  2019-03-31 Store A
 3 peach   label4a 21    2019-03-31 Store A
 4 peach   label4b  0.3  2019-03-31 Store A
 5 peach   label1   5    2019-06-30 Store A
 6 peach   label2   0.46 2019-06-30 Store A
 7 peach   label4a 19    2019-06-30 Store A
 8 peach   label4b  0.4  2019-06-30 Store A
 9 peach   label1   4    2019-09-30 Store A
10 peach   label2   0.1  2019-09-30 Store A
# ... with 86 more rows
```

and then Ggplot2/plotting the date with something like this:

```
dta_long %>% filter(label == 'label1') %>% ggplot(aes(date, value, colour = product)) + 
geom_line() + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", 
date_labels = "%b-%y", limits = c((min(dta_long$date)-34), max = max(dta_long$date)))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like the type of problem that you will save time by doing manually rather than finding a programmatic way of converting it unfortunately. How are you reading this data into R? It may be easier to import it differently rather than converting it.

Comment: I'm importing it from Excel's Binary (.xlsb) Workbooks using `read_xlsb` from the readxlsb package. I've imagined I could get the indices/positions with the dates and then using that to add the dates and from there use the dates and keys to pivot the data. Something like that.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at `tidyxl` and `unipivotr` to find an easier way of extracting your data.

Comment: I wasn’t aware of [tag:unipivotr]. Thanks. I will take a look at it. Unfortunately [tag:tidyxl] does not support the binary file format `.xlsb`, according to it [cran page][(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyxl/vignettes/tidyxl.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following will work for your issue. I make the following assumptions:

1. Groups in each sheet are grouped according to date and that each group contains four variables
2. That the values you want to represent are always in rows 8-11 of the spreadsheet
3. A sheet represents a single store and the store name will in the third row and second column of the spreadsheet

```r
dta_wide1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "peach", "dragonfruit", "honeydew", "huckleberry", "", ""), V2 = c("ABC", "some info", "Store A", "", "As of 31/03/2019", "label1", "", "7", "5", "6", "1", "(a) some useless clutter", "(b) more not relevent information"), V3 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.5", "0.4", "0.8", "0.3", "", ""), V4 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "21", "21", "87", "21", "", ""), V5 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.3", "0.1", "0.4", "0.2", "", ""), V6 = c("", "", "", "", "As of 30/06/2019", "label1", "", "5", "2", "3", "7", "", ""), V7 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.46", "0.72", "0.7", "0.8", "", ""), V8 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "19", "22", "85", "25", "", ""), V9 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.4", "0.1", "0.3", "0.2", "", ""), V10 = c("", "", "", "", "As of 30/09/2019", "label1", "", "4", "1", "4", "8", "", ""), V11 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.1", "0.3", "0.6", "0.22", "", ""), V12 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "21", "23", "71", "27", "", ""), V13 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.3", "0.1", "0.4", "0.2", "", ""), V14 = c("", "", "", "", "As of 31/12/2019", "label1", "", "8", "6", "9", "9", "", ""), V15 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label2", "0.7", "0.87", "0.55", "0.33", "", ""), V16 = c("", "", "", "", "", "label4", "label4a", "24", "25", "99", "35", "", ""), V17 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "label4b", "0.3", "0.1", "0.4", "0.2", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))


## Calculate the number of groups of data in the spreadsheet
d1grps <- (ncol(dta_wide1) - 1) / 4 # Divide by 4 due to assumption #1 above

dnew1 <- as_tibble(dta_wide1) %>%
    ## Take rows that contain data (see assumption #2 above)
    slice(8:11) %>% 
    mutate(
        ## Get dates from the original data frame and remove empty cells
        ## (need `unname()` or else this will overwrite variables)
        !!!as.data.frame(slice(dta_wide1, 5) %>% select(seq(2, ncol(.), 4)) %>% unname()),
        ## Get store from second column (see assumption #3 above)
        store = dta_wide1[3, 2] 
    ) %>%
    ## Create variable names for each variable by group
    setNames(
        c("product", paste0(
            c("label1_", "label2_", "label4a_", "label4b_"), 
            rep(1:d1grps, each = 4)
        ),
        paste0("date_", 1:d1grps), "store" 
    )) %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = !any_of(c("product", "store")),
        names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)",
        names_to = c(".value", "group")
    ) %>%
    mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(sub("As of ", "", date)))
```

And the final tibble in long format:

```r
# A tibble: 16 x 8
   product     store   group label1 label2 label4a label4b date      
   <chr>       <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <date>    
 1 peach       Store A 1     7      0.5    21      0.3     2019-03-31
 2 peach       Store A 2     5      0.46   19      0.4     2019-06-30
 3 peach       Store A 3     4      0.1    21      0.3     2019-09-30
 4 peach       Store A 4     8      0.7    24      0.3     2019-12-31
 5 dragonfruit Store A 1     5      0.4    21      0.1     2019-03-31
 6 dragonfruit Store A 2     2      0.72   22      0.1     2019-06-30
 7 dragonfruit Store A 3     1      0.3    23      0.1     2019-09-30
 8 dragonfruit Store A 4     6      0.87   25      0.1     2019-12-31
 9 honeydew    Store A 1     6      0.8    87      0.4     2019-03-31
10 honeydew    Store A 2     3      0.7    85      0.3     2019-06-30
11 honeydew    Store A 3     4      0.6    71      0.4     2019-09-30
12 honeydew    Store A 4     9      0.55   99      0.4     2019-12-31
13 huckleberry Store A 1     1      0.3    21      0.2     2019-03-31
14 huckleberry Store A 2     7      0.8    25      0.2     2019-06-30
15 huckleberry Store A 3     8      0.22   27      0.2     2019-09-30
16 huckleberry Store A 4     9      0.33   35      0.2     2019-12-31
```

And the plot that you wanted:

```r
ggplot(dnew1, aes(x = date, y = label2, color = product, group = product)) +
    geom_line()
```

The code should be amenable to an expanding number of dates in each spreadsheet, and you could write a function to programmatically find the number of groups rather than relying on changing the variable `d1grps` to set the number of groups.

Even though this should work, it might be less of a headache for you to write the contents into a text file and manipulate the text rather than use `dplyr` in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I saves your two sample data-sets and stored them in separate .xlsb-files.
data looks like this:

[image]

[image]

maybe this will help... the solution works for both samnple sets provided, so give it a go.
The code is assuming that all data has the same format, so all info is always in the same rows, and the storename is always in the same column.

```
library( readxlsb )
library( cellranger )
library( tidyverse )
library( data.table )

#get filesnames to read
read.these.files <- list.files( path = "./temp/", 
                                pattern = ".*\\.xlsb",
                                full.names = TRUE,
                                recursive = FALSE )
#now read the data to a list, using lapply()
#  assuming the data needed is in the first sheet of the .xlsb-file
L <- lapply( read.these.files, readxlsb::read_xlsb, sheet = 1, range = cellranger::cell_limits() )
#now we can loop over the read in data in list 'L', and perform operations
L.dt <- lapply( L, function(x) {
  #get store_name
  store_name = x[2,2]
  #get the data
  df1 <- x[7:10,]
  #set the colmanes (=labels) right
  colnames <- x[5:6,]
  colnames[ colnames == "" ] <- NA
  names(df1) <- colnames %>% tidyr::fill( names(colnames) ) %>% slice(2)
  names(df1)[1] <- "product"
  #melt df1 to long format
  df1 <- df1 %>% tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = tidyselect::starts_with("label"), names_to = "label" )
  #set the dates right
  dates <- x[4, ]
  dates <- dates %>% tidyr::pivot_longer( cols = tidyselect::everything())
  dates[ dates == "" ] <- NA
  dates <- tidyr::fill( dates, value ) %>% dplyr::slice(2:n() )
  #add the dates and storename and tidy the .copy column
  df1 <- df1 %>% 
    dplyr::mutate( date  = rep( dates$value, nrow(df1) / length( dates$value) ),
            store = store_name ) %>%
    dplyr::select( -.copy )
})
#create a names list, based on the sourecefile-names
names(L.dt) <- basename( read.these.files )
#now, bind the list of alterend data together into one _long_ data set
L.dt_tbl <- bind_rows(L.dt, .id = 'id')
L.dt_tbl %>% dplyr::mutate(date = str_sub(date, start= -10)  %>%
             lubridate::dmy() ) -> L.dt_tbl
'
```

Convert `value` to type `double`,

```
dta_long <- type_convert(L.dt_tbl, cols(
  `Type of NPE` = col_character(),
  `What NPE` = col_character(),
  value = col_double(),
  institut = col_character()
))
```

Final data,

```
dta_long
# A tibble: 96 x 6
   id             product label   value date       store  
   <chr>          <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <date>     <chr>  
 1 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label1   7    2019-03-31 Store A
 2 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label2   0.5  2019-03-31 Store A
 3 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label4a 21    2019-03-31 Store A
 4 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label4b  0.3  2019-03-31 Store A
 5 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label1   5    2019-06-30 Store A
 6 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label2   0.46 2019-06-30 Store A
 7 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label4a 19    2019-06-30 Store A
 8 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label4b  0.4  2019-06-30 Store A
 9 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label1   4    2019-09-30 Store A
10 dta_wide1.xlsb peach   label2   0.1  2019-09-30 Store A
# ... with 86 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I ran your code. I get an error when I run your code saying that I _cannot subset columns that don't exist_, as the column `.copy` doesn't exist. However, I realize I should have made it clearer that I am looking for a _flexible solution that can be used in a loop_. Hence the two data sets in the reproducible example.

Comment: I imagine I would need to get the positions of the _dates_ in row 5 in the data provided; `dta_wide1[5, ]` and `dta_wide2[5, ]`. Then build from there; count the number of quarters in that given block based, inset the dates in a column, and so forth. Also, as I mention, I am looking for a solution that can help me persuade my research group to use R, hence my bounty and the point about a solution that is _simple/smart/clean_.

Comment: import in a loop? Why not add the filenames into a vector/list ( ussing `list.files()`, and 'loop' it with `lapply()`

Comment: It doesn't have to be a loop per se. Main thing is that the _the call is flexible_ and able to handle _data with varying width_ that needs to pivoted _from wide to long_. I guess a `lapply()` call would work too.

Comment: The code above handles date with different width in your sample date (i.e. 2 and 4 quarters) It can hande up to n quarters, as long as the 'blocks' of quarters are the same format...

Comment: I see. Thanks. I still get an error that I cannot subset columns that don't exist. Don't you get that?  Could possible demonstrate what you mean by _adding  the filenames into a vector/list (using `list.files()`, and 'loop' it with `lapply()`_?

Comment: updated code with some sample-*.xlsb-files... and rasding with `lapply()`

Comment: I do not get any error when rinning the code, but I do get a warning -messae `Warning messages:
1: Duplicate column names detected, adding .copy variable `.. you can suppress these warnings if you want with `suppressWarnings()`

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks a lot! Very illustrative with the `lapply()` call.  I am currently working to reduce the number of packages, i.e. rewrite the [tag:data.table] to [tag:tidyverse]. (my research group gets very reluctant whenever I introduce new packages).  I think I fixed the `.copy` error. I appreciate you keep developing your answer!